# Play Framework 2.1 ebean construction

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I just started using Play Framework 2.1.1 as a Java developer.

Got some eBeans from an existing database and I'm building a RESTful architecture to serve and save those beans from a RESTful client web application.

I have the following beans definitions. Feed is the core object of the application. For simplicity I have not included getters and setters and many other beans, I'm focusing on the ones that give me troubles:

```
@Entity
public class Feed extends Model implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    Long feedId;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @JsonManagedReference("feed-item")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "feed")
    List<Item> items;
    @JsonManagedReference("feed-userFeed")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "feed")
    List<UserFeed> userFeeds;
}

@Entity
public class Item extends Model implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    Long itemId;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Long urlId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "url_id")
    Url url;
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
    Timestamp itemPublishedAt;
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
    Timestamp itemUpdatedAt;
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
    Timestamp createdAt;
    @Version
    Timestamp updatedAt;
    Long feedId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference("item-feed")
    @JoinColumn(name = "feed_id")
    Feed feed;
    Long urlId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "url_id")
    Url url;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "item")
    @JsonManagedReference("item-unseen")
    List<Unseen> unseen;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "item")
    @JsonManagedReference("item-score")
    List<Score> scores;
}

@Entity
public class User extends Model implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    Long userId;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JsonManagedReference("user-userFeed")
    List<UserFeed> userFeeds;
    @OneToMany
    @JsonManagedReference("user-userTag")
    List<UserTag> userTags;
    @OneToMany
    @JsonManagedReference("user-unseen")
    List<Unseen> unseen;
    @OneToMany
    @JsonManagedReference("user-score")
    List<Score> scores;
}

@Entity
public class Score extends Model implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    Long scoreId;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Long itemId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference("score-item")
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    Item item;
    Long userId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference("score-user")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;
}
```

Here's my feed controller:

```
import me.zenfeed.model.Feed;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;

import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class FeedController extends Controller
{
    public static Result delete(Long id)
    {
        new Model.Finder<>(Long.class, Feed.class).byId(id).delete();
        return ok();
    }

    /* return a JSON with all of the objects found*/
    public static Result get()
    {
        return ok(Json.toJson(new Model.Finder<>(Long.class, Feed.class).fetch("userFeeds", new FetchConfig().query()).where().eq("userFeeds.userId", Long.parseLong(session("connectedUserId"))).findList()));
    }

    /* accept a JSON with the object to save and return a JSON with the new object*/
    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result post()
    {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        Feed f = Json.fromJson(json, Feed.class);
        f.save();
        return ok(Json.toJson(f));
    }

    /* accept a JSON with the object to save and return a JSON with the new object*/
    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result put(Long id)
    {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        Feed f = Json.fromJson(json, Feed.class);
        f.update(id);
        return ok(Json.toJson(f));
    }
}
```

Here's a custom function I use to make a query on the DB with some parameters:

```
List<Item> l = new Model.Finder<>(Long.class, Item.class)
.select("itemId, feedId, urlId, title, description, content, author, categories, itemPublishedAt, itemUpdatedAt, wordCount, fresh, vector, createdAt, updatedAt")
.fetch("unseen", "itemId", new FetchConfig().query())
.fetch("scores", "score", new FetchConfig().query())
.fetch("feed.userFeeds", "userId", new FetchConfig().query())
.where()
.eq("feed.userFeeds.userId", Long.parseLong(session("connectedUserId")))
.eq("feed.feedId", feedId)
.orderBy("scores.score")
.findList();
```

I have several problems I would like help with:

<del>- When I try a POST request that calls the method post() of this controller I get the following exception: 

    [RuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'user-score': no back reference property found from type [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class me.zenfeed.model.Score]]]

    I think I put the back reference in the Score model correctly, but I don't understand... Are my ebeans correct?
    Is there something wrong in my controller? Can something be made better?</del>

I now understand I saw a wrong tutorial. The argument for @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference must be the same. So for feed-item relationship the correct annotations are @JsonManagedReference("feed-item") and @JsonBackReference("feed-item").

- As you can see I tried to format the Timestamp objects with an HTML5 like format, but with no luck. I always get the Long number. Should I make a conversion to a Date object? If yes where?

<del>- When I run the query with my custom function I get the URL object populated, even though I clearly excluded it from my select statement (I only would like the URL_ID, not the entire object).</del>

I went manual way with the generation of an HashMap for the properties I care of and gave that to the Json.toJson() method.

Thank you for your help.